# Can I use a formula written in a cell as text?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet called "data" with 10 columns. One of them is "Team Leader Name".

I created 7 sheets called the team leaders first names:
"tom"
"mike"
"michael"
...

I wrote **in each sheet** the following formulas
in B1

```
=GetSheetName()
```

and in A4

```
=QUERY(Data!$A$1:$J$18317;"SELECT WHERE J='"&B1&"'")
```

So in each sheet, I can filter data for each team leader, while I update data in "Data".

Now I want to update the query, but I do not want to change it 7 times.

Can I just write the formula in a cell, and then reference that as a formula, so I can change it just once for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation and spreadsheet, one solution is to use a script :

```
function rimpiazzare(txt){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var regex = /\[[A-Z0-9]{2,}\]/g
  txt.match(regex).forEach(function(ad){
    try{
      var val = sh.getRange(ad.replace(/\[|\]/g,'')).getValue()
      txt = txt.replace(ad,val)
    }catch(e){}
  })
  return txt
}
```

then, in data!I3 you can write

```
SELECT * WHERE F='[B1]'
```

and in individual sheet

```
=QUERY(data!$A$1:$F$7; rimpiazzare(data!I3) )
```

[take a copy of the spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPyytSYD_Hciq-Af70CGcIsuC_9Uvfff9ld9T4QIzm4/edit?usp=sharing)

## edit

Note that to reactivate formulas when loading the spreadsheet, you will need to add a dummy parameter and change the value by onOpen

```
function onOpen(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('data')
  // to re-activate the formulas
  sh.getRange('J3').setValue(!sh.getRange('J3').getValue())
}
```

that means also to add this dummy parameter to the function

```
=QUERY(data!$A$1:$F$7; rimpiazzare(data!I3;data!J3) )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand what you mean, add a dummy parameter to each of `=GetSheetName()` for instance

```
=GetSheetName(Data!$L$1)
```

and put a checkbox in L1 of Data tab, even if this parameter is not called from the function GetSheetName. To update, you will only have to check or uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: no sorry, i meant something different.

i want to write
=QUERY(Data!$A$1:$J$18317;<query from a cell value in some sheet>

so i can create a new sheet "FORMULAS" and in A1 i want to write 
SELECT WHERE J='&B1&'

and in each sheet i can use 
=QUERY(Data!$A$1:$J$18317;Formulas!$A$1)

Comment: so, can you give a link to a sample spreadsheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o4SFx7Aon2ZuhApLMWpwkLguFRQO-wuMBkoQ0sqGec0/edit?usp=sharing i re-created the example

thank you so much.

basically what i want to do is to change the formulas in "tom", "paul" and  "john" tabs so they use the formula writte in data!I3

SELECT WHERE J='"&B1&"'

so in the future if I need to update this query (adding date filters for example) i can simply update just 1 cell

Comment: ok, it's clear for me now ... let me try to solve ...

Comment: Much more difficult than I expect first.